# Pandas: find duplicate items by date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe of two columns date and engine like below. I need a query to tell

`"Is there any repeated engineID withing the time period 2016-01-01 to 2016-06-30 ?"`

```
engineID    Date
1133        2016-01-24
1133        2016-02-20
1132        2016-03-11
1643        2016-02-07
1165        2016-02-24
1724        2016-01-12
1133        2016-11-23
```

So here the last row should not be included in the answer.

Final Answer:

```
engineID    Date
1133        2016-01-24
1133        2016-02-20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`pandas`**
*Using `between` and `duplicated` with `keep=False`*
This answer avoids the overhead of creating a new index and in the process overwriting the old one by simply using boolean indexing with two boolean arrays.  The first determines if the dates in the `Date` column are `between` the requisite dates.  The second determines if there are duplicates.

```
df[df.Date.between('2016-01-01', '2016-06-30') & df.engineID.duplicated(keep=False)]

   engineID       Date
0      1133 2016-01-24
1      1133 2016-02-20
```

---

**`numpy`**
*`pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`*
In this answer I create two boolean arrays to replace the `between` functionality.  I use `pd.factorize` and `np.bincout` to determine what the duplicates are.

```
d = df.Date.values
s, e = pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01', '2016-06-30']).values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.engineID.values)
m = np.bincount(f)[f] > 1
df[(s <= d) & (d <= e) & m]

   engineID       Date
0      1133 2016-01-24
1      1133 2016-02-20
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df[df.Date.between('2016-01-01', '2016-06-30') & df.engineID.duplicated(keep=False)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop

%%timeit
d = df.Date.values
s, e = pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01', '2016-06-30']).values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.engineID.values)
m = np.bincount(f)[f] > 1
df[(s <= d) & (d <= e) & m]
1000 loops, best of 3: 398 µs per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df.set_index('Date').loc['2016-01-01':'2016-06-30']
d1[d1.duplicated(['engineID'], keep=False)].reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the date as the index then you can use [Partial String Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) and `duplicated`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df_out = df.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-06-30']
df_out[df_out.duplicated(['engineID'],keep=False)].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        Date  engineID
0 2016-01-24      1133
1 2016-02-20      1133
```

Comment: `df.set_index` should use the option `inplace=True` or assign to another variable

Comment: You are correct. I missed that thanks for the correction.